# A paired-sample t-test, but for multiple data points per subject

Tags: t-test, paired-data

My data comes from subjects performing the same task under different conditions—in other words, I have data from each subject under both the control condition and the experimental condition. This seems like a good place to use a paired-sample t-test.

However, each subject also performed the task 32 times (16 under one condition, 16 under the other).

Is there a good way to modify the paired-sample t-test to include multiple measurements of each subject, rather than just one? I know I could just take the mean of the measurements and perform the t-test on that, but that would be completely ignoring the variance within each subject.

Comment: In R, you can use the t.test.cluster function in the Hmisc package for this purpose, and enter participant ID as "cluster" argument of the function. Not sure about other software. You might also want to consider using a multilevel regression, in which you could regress your outcome on group and include random intercept of participant, which takes care of the data being clustered within participants.

Comment: You could also use a mixed model. Consider to add tags [tag:mixed-model] or [tag:multilevel-analysis]. Also look here in the side-panel, where there is a section **Related**. Some of those posts might interest you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mixed model, with random effects for each subject. In R something like

```r
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer( response ~ condition + (1 | Subject)
summary(mod)
```

where `condition` is a factor with levels `experimental`  and  `control`.